# Different root and sub-folder permissions for the same user - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently I've got a task for creating document management system for my company using the SharePoint 2013.
I'm still new in this area and maybe that's the reason I cannot solve my problem with the permissions.
So,I have one root folder and couple of sub folders with other sub folders in it.

Structure Example:

ROOT Folder

-----> A folder

```
--------> A1 folder

       ---------> A1.1 folder
       ---------> A1.2 folder

-------->A2 folder
```

----->B folder

```
--------> B1 folder

       ---------> B1.1 folder
       ---------> B1.2 folder

-------->B2 folder
```

etc..

Is it possible to make same user to have different permissions for (lets say) folder A1 (only read,view) and for sub-folder A1.1 and A1.2 (Edit/update)?

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Normally permissions are inherited. For example , if user A has Read permission on folder, all the subfolders will have same permission automatically.

However, you can break this inheritance and you can configure individual permissions at each folder or even at each item as well.

At the same time, you should not break this inheritance too often. Think of having separate site, subsite or library altogether for this purpose.

See these article for best practices:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955%28v=office.15%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169567%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Madhur , it helped me a lot and sorry I'm late with my answer , but I've stuck with another problems now I would so grateful if you can help me again...Ill open another issue for it..THANKS!